# Why same function signature with only difference that the other get the param by const is a redefenition?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int t) {
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
}

void f(const int t) {
    std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    const int i = 5;
    f(i);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
q2.cpp: In function ‘void f(int)’:
q2.cpp:7:6: error: redefinition of ‘void f(int)’
 void f(const int t) {
      ^
q2.cpp:3:6: error: ‘void f(int)’ previously defined here
 void f(int t) {
```

Why it's considered redefenition if the following compiles fine?

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int& t) {
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
}

void f(const int& t) {
    std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
}

int main() {
     int i = 5;
    f(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it because sending `int` by value copies it? If so have they made it on purpose because it's senseless to pass by value and make it const or is it some limitation of C++11?

Comment: Because it's senseless to have both `const` and non-`const` when you take by value. That constness communicates no useful information to the caller. Either way, they both accept the same arguments and make the same guarantees to the user. That constness is only relevant to the implementation of the function, where it prevents you modifying the argument's copy if you want that protection.

Answer (score 3):

The rule is that top-level `const` qualifiers are discarded when the compiler looks at overloads. So `f(const int)` is treated as `f(int)`, which is a redefinition of the previous `f(int)`. The reason for this rule is that any argument that can be passed to `f(int)` can also be passed to `f(const int)`, because, as you say, the call copies the value.

The reason that this doesn't apply to `f(const int&)` is that the `const` here is not at the top level. From the caller's perspective, the difference between `f(const int&)` and `f(int&)` is that when you have, for example, `const int i = 3;`, you can pass that to `f(const int&)` but you can't pass it to `f(int&)`.